# how to make dialog stay on the screen all the time

Tags: c++, windows, c++builder

I am very new to borland c++. I have an assignment to do. Ok, While the user is working on the main window, I want dialog which gives nice tips how to do things stay on the screen.

I really appreciate if anybody can help.

Comment: the same dialog is called from different routines, so for some other routines I need this dialog to be modal, so I had tried to make it not modal, when I call it from the routine which requires this dialog stay all the time, but when I disable showmodal I can't see the dialog at all

Comment: what version of Borlands compiler?

Answer (score 1):

You should first get the window handle and then use the following Win API method:

```
SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);
```

More details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx

Cheers,

Comment: thanks for quick response, I will let you know if I will be able to resolve it

Comment: I have used CWnd* pWnd = NULL;
HWND hWnd = pWnd->GetSafeHwnd(); to get the window handle, but couldn't figure out what library to include. Any help?

Comment: Are you including Windows.h? #include <Windows.h>

Comment: Ok I was able to make it work, only thing I needed to do was to set FormStyle to fsStayOnTop. Thanks a lot for everybody who responded to me

Comment: `CWnd` is a Microsoft MFC class, it does not exist in the Borland VCL world.